# How does the Dalvik VM save and restore its registers between method calls?

Tags: android, jvm, dalvik, cpu-architecture, vm-implementation

Semantically, the Dalvik VM has a fresh set of registers for each method, and does not have instructions to access the call stack.  But in terms of its implementation, the registers should be saved somehow on method calls and restored on method returns.  How does the (Google's implementation of) Dalvik do this?

Comment: Is the source for the Google Dalvik implementation accessible? Also note, there is a difference between *Dalvik byte-code* not having access to a "call stack" and the *implementation* which executes such byte-code not having such access. (It *must* have some way of maintaining state, look at the contracts for methods calls as a start ;-)

Comment: It just pushes the previous context onto its internal call stack when a method is entered and pops it when a method is exited.

Comment: @pst: Android is open source, of course the source is accessible :)

Comment: I figured it out by myself.  The relevant source files are [header.cpp][1] and [gotoTargets.cpp][2].

The Dalvik registers actually reside in Dalvik's call stack, around the frame pointer `fp`.  So the register *n* is actually `fp[` *n* `]`.  When a method calls another, the arguments are copied on top of the caller's registers, and the frame pointer is decremented to make room for the callee's registers.

  [1]: https://github.com/android/platform_dalvik/blob/master/vm/mterp/c/header.cpp
  [2]: https://github.com/android/platform_dalvik/blob/master/vm/mterp/c/gotoTargets.cpp

Answer (score 6):

The registers that dalvik bytecode refers to are not machine registers at all, but they are actually locations on the call stack. Whenever you call into a method, dalvik allocates enough memory on that method's stack frame to hold all the registers that that method needs.

Note that not all calculations will modify the value on the stack immediately, the vm obviously has to load the values into a machine register in order to do the calculations. The results may be kept in a machine register to be used later without immediately writing it back to the corresponding stack location, at the discretion of the VM. The values will be flushed back to the call stack if and when it is needed (i.e. when you call into another method, use various sync constructs, or it needs the register for another calculation, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Here is source repository for dalvik, you may walkthrough to findout implementation. [android source](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)